# Popup Dialogs in web applications

Tags: web-applications, user-interface, usability

Are popup dialogs a good thing as far as web application usability is concerned? I know they break the back button. Are they worth using or should they be used only when you cant avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about window popups then sure they are considered bad usabiltiy practice. A user feels that he is about to view an advertisement and closes it all sudden. Also it doesnt falls into seamless view of site. Popups are sure a distraction we have currently been working on a project where we use Lightbox modalbox from jQuery to avoid usage of popups which have been very well recieved by users. See

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ for examples of Lightboxes.

I always like to read http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html for usability concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You may not count this as the answer you wanted, but I have used CSS dialog popups with great effect in some of my web apps.

See here: [CSS Message Boxes with Different Types](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2008/05/22/CSS-Message-Boxes-for-different-message-types.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

With the arrival of Web 2.0, it is better to use dialog boxes like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)